# How to add multiple products on clicking add power button

Tags: products, multiple, popup

I want to know how to add multiple products as a popup on clicking addpower button.. The process we select a frame and then add a power to it . So, once we click on add to power a popup displays with different quality lens that will be added to the frame price and we will have 6 to 8 lenses we can only select one lense at a time which will be added to the frame price. Please help me. I have aattavhed the screenshot as well or if there are any paid plugins you can recommend me.

Please find the link for add power button[image]
http://www.lenskart.com/vincent-chas...unglasses.html

Comment: Have you tried Magento different type of products and default custom options available. I think your requirement can be fulfilled by that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all simple products you can follow the steps as Related product section given by default Magento. You just need to create group of your simple products and you will need to pass qty and ids in hidden with add to cart form. By this way you can add multiple products in single add to cart button.